# Chosing civilization types for an interstellar galaxy-wide world

Tags: space-colonization, civilization, artificial-intelligence

So, I need multiple civilizations interacting in an interstellar world of the size of a galaxy.

But my current view now is that all interstellar civilizations will be AI-driven and based and physically manifested as robots, regardless of what was the initial race that created them.

So, should I consider non-robotic civilizations at all or they are absolutely improbable?

It seems to me that AI inevitably surpasses any evolutionary-developed intelligence. All my galaxy should be populated only by robotic races.

Comment: Butlerian Jihad as in Frank Herbert's [*Dune*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))? Benevolent coexistence as in Iain M. Banks's [*Culture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_series)? All-out war as in [*Battlestar Galactica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica)? Ignoring the issue altogether as in *Star {Trek, Wars}*, the Honorverse and so on and so on? It is pretty much your choice as the author.

Comment: Some say Singularity is inevitable and other say human will become immortal by that time just like 2 sides of a coin

Comment: "It seems to me that AI inevitably surpasses any evolutionary-developed intelligence". Well thats up to you. For today we don't know whether true AI will ever be achieved or not. If you decide it can be achieved in your story you get to set the constraints for it. I would advice you to post what you have decided upon what your AI can do and what it can't. Then we can help you explore wether or not non-robotic civs might flourish.

Comment: If as a worldbuilder you've decided that AI inevitably surpasses any evolutionary-developed intelligences in the world you're building then you've already answered your own question. If as a worldbuilder you believe that in your world thinking machines will always fundamentally lack a certain, spark that humanity possesses then the answer may be different. In either case the answer depends on how intelligence works in your world.

Comment: @sphennings this is a real-world question

Comment: We're a worldbuilding site not a real-world question site. If you're asking about the real world then you shouldn't ask your question here.

Comment: @sphennings physically real world that may be a continuation of the current world in the future.

Comment: Regardless of what you choose to base your fictional world on how it develops is entirely up to you. Perhaps humans are the only sentient life in the galaxy and we kill ourselves off before creating general AI. Or a myriad of other possible circumstances you get to decide for yourself even if the physics of your world work exactly like reality.

Comment: Why the view that "all interstellar civilizations will be AI-driven"? There are reams and reams of compelling and sufficiently believable sci-fi that have organic interstellar societies. Some of the greatest works of sci-fi ever written are set in non-robotic interstellar civilizations. You don't read *Dune* or *Foundation* and think, "this is unbelievable, these characters should be robots".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie those sci-fi pieces (like Dune, for instance) are not convincing (or outdated): how and why a civilization would reject computers? And now (after 2023) they would not be convincing even if they had computers.

Comment: @Anixx My point is that non-robotic interstellar civilizations are not so obviously improbable that they are downright unsuitable for a work of fiction - that notion is easily shown to be untrue by observing the vast quantity of fiction featuring organic starfarers. Most people are wholly unbothered by organic lifeforms flying around the stars in fiction. Even if such races are "absolutely improbable", they're clearly still believable enough to appear in sci-fi *all the time*.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie yes, they are suitable for sci-fi in general, but the point is, they look unrealistic to me, so if the chosen principle is plausibility, it looks like they should not be included.

Comment: @Anixx Then you have answered your own question and posing it here is useless. **You**, as the author, are the one that defines what your worldbuilding will be. You've, very clearly, defined the future as completely AI based, and appear unwilling to listen to counter arguments. That's your choice. But, you should recognize that it **is your choice**. We have no actual information as to what the future brings. Thus, there's no way to *definitely know* what it will be, except in hindsight.

Comment: I think the first two questions you need to ask yourself are: how fast can two distant solar systems communicate with eachother, and how fast can individuals travel from one star system to another? If it takes more than a lifetime to travel from one star system to another, the galaxy-wide civilisation will not be the same as if it takes half an hour to cross the galaxy.

Answer (score 6):

There may be a crucial point in the development of a civilisation that determines their course. I posit different pathways which occur in semi-isolation. This would give the possibility of certain civs. developing AI faster, others seeing their example and determining their own course after evaluating what they see:

**Full artificial:**

1. This may range from the elimination of organic life altogether, it's replacement, perhaps through conquest by the robots/AI.
2. Through the middle-ground of having AIs imprinted with remnant human consciousness and organic bodies being discarded.

**Integration:**

1. A culture successfully "tames the AI monster" before it can get too ambitious. There are systems in society wholly run by AI, but an essentially cooperative relationship occurs, one of synergy. Cybernetic bodies and AI-Brain integration is common.
2. The Culture is totally subsumed by the AI "servants". Humans become helpless dependants, their every whim catered for, except that of freedom and self-determination. Perhaps VR integration of human minds is common here.

**Naturalists, rejection of AI.:**

1. This can go to the extent of full [Luddite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luddite), leading to technological regression to pre-industrial settlements.
2. Technology is present, but limited to non-AI. Essentially tech of the year 2000, plus any scientific developments that might occur, with computers being programmable tools with no independent will.

**We then need to look at alternative pathways:**

Survival by genetic adaptation to elude the AIs. The science of genetics is keeping pace with the development of AI, I foresee civilisations that evolve camouflage and a certain unpredictability to defy conquest by AI. This would inevitably lead to another kind of "arms race", increasing the fitness of both predatory AI and prey "humans" (or what "humanity" becomes in their future).

Pirates, smugglers and brigands. A lot of Cyborgs here, some rogue AIs, predatory humans and meta-humans - perhaps even some of all of those working together.

The religious/diplomatic groups. These would rely on donated support and money gleaned from brokering cultural and trade relations. Tough to say, maybe some would be full normal human, some not - as the story demands. Some may be entirely space-bourn, not having a home-base.

Extra-galactic voyagers. What do they find? Do any return? Does anything *follow them*?

Answer (score 5):

Survival of the fittest and convergent evolution seems to be leading in the direction you say: once AI is developed, it takes over and continues on its own.

However if we look at past historical examples we see that other factors come into play: though the Romans were more advanced than most of the tribe living around their empire, their expansion stopped due to other limiting factor. Similar things happened to other empires, so it's not implausible to think that it will happen also on galactic level.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you absolutely should**

The Universe is a pretty large place, just on Planet Earth we've had multiple, distinct periods of life - that have risen and fallen over millions of years.

Just because Civilization 1 on planet 1 reached a state of full AI robots 10 million years ago does not mean that Civilization 2 on planet 2 are at the same point.

Hell, on Earth we have civilizations that can use digital technology and groups of isolated tribes that would murder you as a magic-man/witch/sorcery if they saw our modern technology.

So yes, there will absolutely be non-AI civilizations in your world.

**What the existing AI does with them once it discovers them could be an interesting plot-point in your World.**

E.g. does it eradicate them because of them being inferior?
Does it encourage them to assimilate to their culture?
Does it say 'Life is suffering, therefore in order to be kind, I must force them to join us'?
Does it leave them be, knowing that eventually, they too will achieve AI sentience?

Comment: But would be the non-AI civilizations interstellar?

Comment: @Anixx - Assuming Interstellar travel is possible, there's no reason why it couldn't be discovered before AI, unless you make it a rule in your world that only super-powerful AI is capable of discovering the means for interstellar traffic due to *insert story driven reasons here*

Comment: I want a world based on real-world physical laws. I do not see how intertellar travel can be accomplished before AI. The AI tech now looks quite trivial and not even requiring a lot of computing power.

Comment: @Anixx - As I said, it's your world - you get to make the rules. If the laws of physics are such that Interstellar travel is possible, then it's possible for them to be discovered. If you want to make it so that only AI civilizations achieve this, make it a pre-condition *due to story reasons*

Answer (score 2):

I think it is fine to include non-AI interstellar civilizations.

In your comments you've indicated that you want to try to make your universe "realistic." Fiction is always speculative, and obviously we aren't going to work out unknown laws of physics on this board. If you want to have a universe that precludes non-AI interstellar civilizations, there's enough latitude in the known laws of physics for you to get there. And if you want to include non-AI civilizations you can get there as well.

Currently we've made some impressive advances in having ML algorithms generate text and images. This is not really that close to general AI or anything like that. Consider, ChatGPT was trained on a good chunk of the entire body of internet text ([around 300 billion words apparently](https://www.sciencefocus.com/future-technology/gpt-3)). A fast human reads around 300 words per minute, so compare it to a human who's been reading books 24 hours a day for 1,000,000 minutes-almost 2000 years. ChatGPT is an ok writer, but there exist plenty of humans who are better than it, and almost none of them [citation needed] spent 2000 years studying the language. Currently, we have made an impressive tool to create text that looks like existing text, but humans do other things than that, and seem to do much better at learning from very limited data sets.

I'm not saying it is impossible to build a machine which does this. Clearly human brains physically exist, so they could be physically replicated, but this is futuristic enough that you can get away with just making it very hard in your universe if you want.

Digital beings have the advantage that they can be "checkpointed" like a virtual machine. Which is to say, frozen, stored on a hard drive for an interstellar flight, spun up when you get there, and/or copied to make duplicate personalities, etc. Maybe. ChatGPT definitely has this ability. If you want to have your fictional AI be: ChatGPT but artificial general intelligence, then you can give it these abilities. But if the ChatGPT strategy hits a dead-end, and you still want to have AI, then you have all the typical sci-fi AI tropes to go for.

If your species has created consciousness (whatever that is) in some sort of special device, you can consider whatever restrictions you want have for the operation of that device. Maybe consciousness requires continuous power to keep going, and it can't really be usefully serialized to a hard drive. Maybe it is some weird quantum effect and trying to read it for saving will "collapse the waveform" and destroy the consciousness (note: I only had like 1-2 undergrad classes in modern physics and they were quite a while ago, so someone really immersed in that world can probably point to reasons why that is not a correct, but I think most readers would buy this). I mean you can go pick sci-fi concepts as you like, there are too many to list. Maybe it is just as easy to cryogenically freeze biologicals as it is to back up an AI.

---

It isn't clear to me what fundamental advantage an AI has, in building a galactic civilization. In particular, if you want to have a realistic sci-fi universe, I think the table stakes are information doesn't travel faster than 1c, and time dilation applies. [So play with a calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/space-travel). If you want some resources on Canopus, and you want to accelerate at 1g (no need for a magical gravity machine, yay!), then it will take you ~311 years in the reference frame of your planet. Only ~11 years for the passengers. You can send normal humans on the ship, they will only be a little older when they get there, but they will probably want to stay on Canopus because their country on Earth will probably not last 600 years.

So, why do we send people to Canopus? Nobody alive on Earth will survive to recoup their investment. The trip must be one-way, a colonization effort, not a resource gathering one. It is likely motivated by the passengers, not the beings left on Earth. If you've got a civilization where biologicals are the ones who are given the rights to set their own goals, they'll be the ones who go out to colonize.